# how to concatenate the ADC output?

Tags: microcontroller

hey
I need help to write a programe in pic c compiler that can cocatenate S, at the start of ADC out put value(q is the out put  i.e  q = read_adc()  ) and E at the end of ADC output so that i can feed that string to computer by serial port communication.I am using pic microcontroller 16f877A
how to do that pls help me...thanx

Comment: Please give some attention to phrasing your question correctly and provide more information on your environment (programming language, compiler, microcontroller type) and whatever code you have already written. As it is there is no way to answer something like this since we don't even know what language the code is supposed to be in.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience.I am using pic microcontroller pic 16f877A and  pic c compiler.currently in code i am reading the value of ADC long int q and q=read_adc();

Answer (score 0):

Besides the question need more info and isnt detailed, I suppose you are coding in C.
To concatenate a long int to a char you need to use itoa() which will take the int and return a char*, later you just need to do some string process to concatenate them.

Anyway, most of times this is not necessary, because if you need to output the adc value, let's suppose to your serial, you can just first output 'S', then the adc value, and then the 'E'.

Working with strings functions in microcontrollers most of times just causes to load a lot of unused code and lost space.